# Is there a way to have Save Dialog in not tie up with IE 9 tab/browser window?

Tags: internet-explorer, download, internet-explorer-9, download-manager

I just really hate when I close my IE browser, the download/save dialog is close together.
All I want is just to close the browser to give me more display space and memory....

Is there anyway to do that in ie9? Or save file like traditional way?

Comment: Huh? Its not supposed to that since IE8.. ? I know chrome download within itself, but IE opens a window, even if i clsoe IE it still downlaods..

Comment: Now in IE9 you will see a dialog on the bottom of your browser (inside that tab), but if you close your browser, the download dialog will close together... Normally I use some 3rd party download manager so I don't care at home.  But when I am in office I just really hate that lol At least I don't see the download dialog anywhere when I close my browser....

Comment: o no, nvm, I just realize it actually will download in background within the Download Manager Ctrl+J......Just that I won't see the process and won't know when it completed.....